# Shopping cart price rule SKU-A and SKU-B condition

Tags: shopping-cart-price-rules

How can I set a condition if I require two unique SKUs to be purchased first, before a discount is availed?

For example, if SKU 0001 and SKU 0002 exists on the cart, then you'll get 50% OFF. Both SKUs are required.

I already tried the if SKU "contains" SKU002,SKU001 condition, and the if SKU "is" SKU002,SKU001 condition, but it doesn't seem to satisfy what I'm trying to achieve.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you put both the SKU's in a single condition, it will evaluated as an OR condition. So, you will need to put both SKUs in separate conditions.
See the image below as a reference.
[image: Cart Price rules]

Comment: Glad it was helpful